# extract a value from a googlemaps JSON response

Tags: regex, erlang, elixir

[image]
My JSON_Respon from googlemap API give

```
%{ body: body} = HTTPoison.get! url


body = {
   "geocoded_waypoints" : [{ ... },{ ... }],
   "routes" : [{
         "bounds" : { ...},
         "copyrights" : "Map data ©2018 Google",
         "legs" : [
        {
               "distance" : {
                  "text" : "189 km",
                  "value" : 188507
               },
               "duration" : {
                  "text" : "2 hours 14 mins",
                  "value" : 8044
               },
               "end_address" : "Juhan Liivi 2, 50409 Tartu, Estonia",
               "end_location" : {
                  "lat" : 58.3785389,
                  "lng" : 26.7146963
               },
               "start_address" : "J. Sütiste tee 44, 13420 Tallinn, Estonia",
               "start_location" : {
                  "lat" : 59.39577569999999,
                  "lng" : 24.6861104
               },
               "steps" : [
                  { ... },
                  { ... },
                  { ... },
                  { ... },
                  {
                     "distance" : {
                        "text" : "0.9 km",
                        "value" : 867
                     },
                     "duration" : {
                        "text" : "2 mins",
                        "value" : 104
                     },
                     "end_location" : {
                        "lat" : 59.4019886,
                        "lng" : 24.7108114
                     },
                     "html_instructions" : "XXXX",
                     "maneuver" : "turn-left",
                     "polyline" : {
                        "points" : "XXXX"
                     },
                     "start_location" : {
                        "lat" : 59.3943677,
                        "lng" : 24.708647
                     },
                     "travel_mode" : "DRIVING"
                  },
                  { ... },
                  { ... },
                  { ... },
                  { ... },
                  { ... },
                  { ... },
                  { ... },
                  { ... },
                  { ... }
               ],
               "traffic_speed_entry" : [],
               "via_waypoint" : []
            }
         ],
         "overview_polyline" : { ... },
         "summary" : "Tallinn–Tartu–Võru–Luhamaa/Route 2",
         "warnings" : [],
         "waypoint_order" : []
      }
   ],
   "status" : "OK"
}
```

(check the attached image)
in red what I'm getting with with bellow command from [Regex.named_captures](https://hexdocs.pm/elixir/Regex.html#named_captures/3) module

```
%{"duration_text" => duration_text, "duration_value" => duration_value} = Regex.named_captures ~r/duration\D+(?<duration_text>\d+ mins)\D+(?<duration_value>\d+)/, body
```

in bleu (check the attached image), what I want to extract from body
body is the JSON response of my googleAPI url on a browser

Would you please assist and provide the regex ?

Since http://www.elixre.uk/ is down, i'm cant find any api helping to do that

Thanks in advance

Comment: Official documentation is available [on elixir-lang.com website](https://elixir-lang.org/docs.html).

Answer (score 5):

Don't use regexes on a json string.  Instead, convert the json string to an elixir map using [Jason](https://github.com/michalmuskala/jason), [Poison](https://github.com/devinus/poison), etc., then use the keys in the map to lookup the data you are interested in.

Here's an example:

```
json_map = Jason.decode!(get_json())

[first_route | _rest] = json_map["routes"]
[first_leg |  _rest] = first_route["legs"]
distance = first_leg["distance"]

=> %{"text" => "189 km", "value" => 188507}
```

Similarly, you can get the other parts with:

```
duration = first_leg["duration"]
end_address = first_leg["end_address"]
...
...
```